# how to specify redirect url with ajax jQuery redirect

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter-3

I have a form that when I submit the form, it would redirect to the url that I've specified from the controller (function controller as action form). I've made a function controller to process the form, and I have several difference conditions that could make 2 redirect from json result when I submit the form. But I want the ajax to redirect to one of the redirect from the json result.

How could I redirect to the specific redirect from the json result?

the json result :

```js
{"result":"ok","message":"Failed!!! ","redirect":"http:\/\/localhost\/myproject\/approval\/detail\/21?status=approve_failed"}
{"result":"ok","message":"Success!!!","redirect":"http:\/\/localhost\/myproject\/approval\/detail\/21?status=approve_success"}
```

this is how I redirect when I submit the form :

```js
var frm = $('#form-process');

frm.submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: frm.attr('method'),
        url: frm.attr('action'),
        data: frm.serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(res) {
            if (res.result == "ok") {
                if (res.redirect) {
                    window.location.href = res.redirect;
                }
                $.notify("Success. Data saved.", "success");
                $('#modalDateEst').modal('hide');
                table.ajax.reload();
            } else {
                $.notify("System gone wrong's. Please contact Administrator", "error");
            }
        },

        error: function(data) {

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your _"json result"_ is not valid JSON

Comment: @Phil could you tell me why is it not valid?

Comment: You can't send two JSON objects in a single JSON response. If you want to return multiple objects, they need to be in an array.

Comment: You've got two objects and they're not in an array. Paste it into https://jsonlint.com/ and you'll see

Comment: And that raises the question: If the API returns multiple objects, which one do you want to check with `if (res.result == "ok")`?

Comment: I send it in my each conditions by `echo json_encode(array(//the json))`

Comment: @Barmar could you tell me how to make condition if the API returns multiple objects?

Comment: Don't use `echo json_encode()` in the loop. Push each object onto an array, and then use `echo json_encdeo($array);` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. Here's what I do.
I make a variable $redirect in the function that I use in the controller. Then I make some the conditions.

Inside the condition should be :

```php
if (//condition) {
 $arred = array(
     "result" => "ok",
     "message" => "Success!!! ",
     'redirect' => base_url(//my url for the redirect)
 );

 $redirect = $arred;
}
```

so in my function controller would be like :

```php
function something() {
$redirect = "";


if (//condition) {
 //do something
 $arred = array(
     "result" => "ok",
     "message" => "Success!!! ",
     'redirect' => base_url(//my url for the redirect)
 );

 $redirect = $arred;
}


if (//condition2) {
 //do something
 $arred = array(
     "result" => "ok",
     "message" => "Success!!! ",
     'redirect' => base_url(//my url for the redirect)
 );

 $redirect = $arred;
}

//make the json
echo json_encode($redirect);
}
```

note : this solution is only making your jquery redirect to the latest redirect that fill the `$redirect` variable. So if you got multiply redirect, the only redirect that would be used is the latest one. In this case, I just need the latest redirect.  So this is my solution.